# Android: fast and resource saving ListView

Tags: android, listview

i need a listView implementation which has following features:
-resource saving: should hold only elements in memory which are visible +x
-should provide interface to change current element without loading everything
-should load elements from slow resources in background so that interaction is fast

Is there an example for that out there?

thanks
tata

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider looking at Romain Guy's [presentation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6YdwzAvwOA) (beginning) where he explains performance issues with ListView and teaches to use adapters efficiently. (ViewHolder pattern and reusing views).

The video is awesome and he explains how to reach maximum performance and avoid common mistakes in the ListView providing code examples.

Comment: man, It's a video from Google I/O in English:) Where did you spot French? Even subtitles are available.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a sample [here](https://github.com/asabbarwal/EffecientListViewDesign) which uses the ViewHolder and convertview (for re-using views) for an effecient Listview implementation.

Also [this](http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/) article clearly explains the terminology behind the code sample.